# How to hide the private key used for encryption in the client machine?

Tags: azure, api, encryption, private-key, azure-management-api

So the scenario is that i want to basically hide the subscription key of an API , in Azure management service.To access that api , user has to send the subscription key in the header of the request.And i have decided to encrypt that subscription key with a private key for better protection.There's an endless loop , to hide the subscription key we need a private key , and to hide this private key we will need a new key , and so on.But now the question is , is there a way to hide this private key?Or is there a better way to hide/protect this subscription key? Thank you.

Comment: does this answer your question? [Securing a password in source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155187/securing-a-password-in-source-code/4155200#4155200)

Comment: the answers are all about how to protect the key in the code.In my case , there isn't any code involved.

Comment: If there isn't any code involved then the question is off-topic, at least according to the what the [tag itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure) says. Also, there is code involved, namely the user's code where the subscription key also resides.